# Find best paths within multiple tree (multiple nodes in multiple layer)

Tags: algorithm, path, tree, path-finding, directed-acyclic-graphs

The problem is to find best paths(min cost / high score) within multiple nodes in multi-level. Or in other words, within multiple trees which share some same nodes.

For example as seen [in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAy8X.jpg); 
There are several nodes in each level. These connected each other with edges(each edge also has a distance value, but may not use). And each path has a score value from the edge values. The score is joint probability of the path.

So the aim is to find the best paths between these nodes of layers.

the data is seen as follows; 
(first level node, 2 level node, 3 level node ...): score

(1, 1, 1) : 3

(1, 2, 1) : 1

(1, 2, 2) : 6

(1, 2, 3) : 2

(2, 2, 1) : 3

(2, 2, 2) : 4

(2, 2, 3) : 3

(2, 3, 2) : 5

(2, 3, 3) : 4

.....

the result should give 5 paths and these paths should give overall min-cost.

What kind of algorithm should be used for this problem?

Comment: Where are you getting those scores from?  Do the edges have weights not shown in that image?

Comment: yea, I tried to explain in question, but seem it was vague. The edges have weights( weight is the probability of an edge from node(t) to node(t+1)) . And the score is the multiplication of the weights (kind of joint probability) in a path, from top node to the bottom node

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be modeled as a [minimum cost flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) network problem. Let `m` be the number of nodes in each layer. An artificial source `s` is placed above the first layer; `s` is connected to each node of the first layer and each of these `m` edges has its network capacity constrained by `1` and a cost of `0`. Likewise, there is an artificial terminal `t` below the last layer; `t` is connected to each node of the last layer and each of these `m` edges has its network capacity constrained by `1` and a cost of `0`. The problem can be solved by determining a minimum cost flow with amount `m`, which is possible via the [network simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_simplex_algorithm) algorithm.

Comment: This would only work if the graph were unweighted.  His description mentions a "score" for each path, which I assume is the cost of that path?